# Change color alternately using 4 different colors in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5

I did a lot of research about it but I ended up with just using 2 different colors instead of 4. What I want is to change the color alternately using 4 different colors (`blue`, `red`, `green`, `yellow`). What I have is just the two colors. Please see my code below:

```
<?php $colors_counter = 0; ?>
@foreach($posts as $post)

  <div class="header-{{ ($colors_counter%2 == 0) ? 'blue' : 'red' : 'green' : 'yellow' }}">
    {{ $post->name }}
  </div>

  <?php $colors_counter++; ?>
@endforeach
```

**Note**: I'm also using laravel 5 for this.

Comment: Ok good to know. Do you have any questions or problems with this?

Comment: what is `color_counter` ? stores which color key or something?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it is not working when I do the 4 colors.

Comment: It counts the times it has run through for each, I assume, when I look at the code.

Comment: The ternary operator is not usable for that, since it only gives you the option of two outcomes, but you can use the same idea and if clauses to get what you want.

Comment: Why are you using a ternary if you want four options? Ternary is for two options (unless you want to make a big mess). A normal if() or switch will do the job so much cleaner and better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simple Scalable Solution

You can have the colors in a separate array and take mod value of the total count to alternate the colors between the rows.

This solution is scalable and will work for `N` number of colors across `M` number of rows.

This way, the code will work even if you modify the number of colors or rows.

**Scalable Code Logic**

```
$colors = [
    'blue'
    'red',
    'green',
    'yellow',
];
$no = count($colors);

// Then use this inside the loop
$colors[$colors_counter % $no];
```

**Example**

```
$colors = [
    'blue',
    'red',
    'green',
    'yellow',
];

$no = count($colors);

for ($i=0;$i < 10; $i++) {
  echo $colors[$i % $no]."\n";  
}
```

**Output**

```
blue
red
green
yellow
blue
red
green
yellow
blue
red
```

Answer (score 2):

you should define array of colors and use colors_counter as the array index.

```
<?php
  $colors_counter = 0;
  $colors = array(0=>"blue", 1=>"red", 2=>"green", 3=>"yellow");
?>
@foreach($posts as $post)

  <div class="header-{{ $colors[$colors_counter] }}">
    {{ $post->name }}
  </div>

  <?php $colors_counter++; ?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What happens if there is five posts? What color will it be then? ;-) https://3v4l.org/mCjD8

Comment: If the post is greater than 5, I just added an if statement. Anyways, this helps.

Comment: it will have class header- and will log notice about missing index to error log

Comment: @Andreas my solution will handle that scenario

Comment: Just pointing out that you need to reset color counter at four. That's all.

Comment: @RamC I see! Good one